# PowerShell: passing parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, continuous-integration, psexec

I run the script from the file in Jenkins. Command:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe /c echo . | powershell.exe -file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Applications\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy\workspace\Deploy\script.ps1"
```

How can I pass a value for the "build" variable?

Please, help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made mistake in the script. I forgot to insert the following code:

```
Param(
  [int32]$build=0
)
```

[As TheMadTechnician said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26150354), the command to run the script is:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe /c echo . | powershell.exe -file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Applications\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy\workspace\Deploy\script.ps1" -build %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply follow the path with your arguments. Such as:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe /c echo . | powershell.exe -file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Applications\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy\workspace\Deploy\script.ps1" '-build 1.0'
```

You can see the command line syntax for PowerShell.exe [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx). It shows:

```
PowerShell[.exe]
       [-File <FilePath> [<Args>]]
```

If that does not work for you, you can try and dot source the script in a -command scriptblock, such as:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe /c echo . | powershell.exe -command {. "c:\Program Files (x86)\Applications\Jenkins\jobs\Deploy\workspace\Deploy\script.ps1" -build 1}
```

Comment: I also installed 'PowerShell plugin' in Jenkins and added command: .\Deploy\script.ps1 -build 1. Script was completed but the build variable is not passed.

Comment: Added an alternative. I imagine PSExec was cutting off the argument as an invalid argument or some such. Hopefully this resolves that.